# No calculator, find the local maximum of $-x^3 +7x^2 -11x + 5$ in $[2,5]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

**Problem**.  Suppose profit is given by $P(x) = -x^3 +7x^2 -11x + 5$, where $x$ is the price of some product in the interval $[2, 5]$.  What is --- approximately --- the price that maximizes the profit?  Possible answers are $3.9$, $3.3$, $3.7$, $4.1$.

**An attempt**.  The derivative is $P'(x) =  -3x^2 + 14x -11$.  I completed the square to find the roots and I found $$P'(x) = 0 = \left(x - \frac{7}{3}\right)^2 + \frac{11}{3} - \frac{7^2}{3^2}.$$
So the two roots are $$x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{7^2}{3^2} - \frac{11}{3}} + \frac{7}{3}.$$  Then I added the fraction inside the radical to get $16/9 = (49 - 33)/9$, which is fraction of perfect squares --- so far so good. So $$x = \frac{7}{3} \pm \frac{4}{3} = 11/3 \text{ or } 1.$$  But the price couldn't be $x = 1$ because that's outside the interval $[2,5]$.  Hence it must be $x=11/3$, which is $3 + 2/3 \approx 3.7$.

**Question**.  This is a no-calculator problem.  I feel like I brute-forced it.  Is there any clever solution?

Comment: Don’t you have to check/compare endpoints?

Comment: fine, in addition, perform 2nd derivative test to ensure its negative, which indicates you have a local maxima. https://byjus.com/maths/second-derivative-test/

Comment: You're both right, but I reasoned as follows --- for $x < 1$, $P'(x)$ is negative, so the $P(x)$ curve must be decreasing to the left of $x=1$.  Therefore, it must go up to the right of $x=1$ (and then it must go down again because it's a cubic).  (I also computed $P(2)$ and $P(5)$ and found 3 and 0, respectively.)  So, it seems to me that if we observe what happens around the roots of the derivative, we can dispense with the second derivative.  Right?  (When looking around isn't too expensive.  The derivative is a quadratic, so that was easy.) (But that was a lot of computation.)

Comment: I suggest you stick to proven process, namely perform 2nd derivative test. It is fast and simple as well as error-proof.

Comment: What you did is fine. A full explanation to which one of the two roots of the derivative is the local maximum would be this:

The roots of the polynomial are 1 (double) and 5. The polynomial factors as
$$-x^3+7x^2-11x+5=-(x-1)^2(x-5)$$
This is a cubic polynomial that resembles $-x^3$ at $\pm \infty$. 
Therefore the local maximum is between second and third root. In this case, between 1 and 5.

Solving-like you did
$$P\prime(x)=-3x^2+14x-11=0\Rightarrow x=1, \frac {11}3$$

Since 1 is a double root then is also a local minimum. Therefore $\frac {11}3$ is the local maximum.

Comment: One way to speed things up is to just test for rational roots off the bat. If $\pm p/q$ is a root, then $p$ divides the constant and $q$ divides the leading term, so you can just test $\pm 1,\pm 5$ and get the roots immediately. The double root at $1$ means it’s derivative has 1 as a root and so it’s straightforward to factor that without the quadratic formula.

Comment: NoChance, point taken.  WindSoul, thank you for the explanation.  I agree that this is the right way of exposing the fact and I had not quite realized it until now.  Eric, wow!  I need to look into this more carefully.  Loved your approach, but I need to work and understand it.  (I'll ask a question here if I don't get it.) Thank you all so much.

Comment: @Eric, your solution is marvelous.  I think I understand it completely now.  The roots of the cubic told you that $x=1$ is a local minimum and a root of the derivative, with which you factored the derivative to find where the maximum was.  Very nice solution indeed.  Feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This fleshes out Windsoul’s answer with my modification from the comments)

These kinds of questions (especially if the source is a classroom environment) often have rational solutions which can help you avoid messy calculations.

Using the rational root theorem, we can check if it has any roots of the form $\pm p/q$ using the fact that any such root must have the numerator $p$ divide the constant of $P$, $5$, and the denominator must divide the leading coefficient, $1$. This means that the only possible rational solutions are $\pm 1, \pm 5$.

Note also, that there’s a trick when substituting values into polynomials. When I plug in $-5$, I can go from left to right, where I take the leading term $-1$, multiply it by $-5$ to get $5$, add the next term to get $12$, multiply that by $-5$ to get $60$ and continue. Frequently the terms will grow big quickly and you can immediately throw out that possibility.

After getting that $1$ is a root, you can factor it, getting $(x-1)(-x^2+6x-5)$. The same technique gives $1$ is another root getting $-(x-1)^2(x-5)$.

At this point, you can tell the broad behavior of $f$ at a glance, that it comes from infinity, touches the x-axis at $1$, reaches a local maximum before crossing the x-axis at $5$ and going off to negative infinity.

To get the exact value of the local maximum of $f$ we’ll need to take a derivative.
$f’(x)=-3x^2+14x+11$.
Since $f$ had a double root at $1$, we know that $f’(x)$ has a root at $1$, so we can factor it out giving $f’(x)=-3(x-1)(x-11/3)$. Thus, the local maximum is at $11/3$.

A quick double check of $f’’(11/3)=-6\cdot 11/3 +14=-8$ gives that the second derivative is indeed negative confirming that $11/3$ is a local maximum. Similarly, substituting 1 confirms it’s a local minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Let P(x) = -x^3 + 7x^2 - 11x + 5. P'(x) = -3x^2 + 14x -11. The 2 roots of P(x) are 11/3 and 1. Hence, on ]-infinity ;1], P' is negatif, on [1;11/3] P' is positif and on [11/3, + infinity[, P' is negatif. So, this tells us that P is strictely increasing on [1, 11/3], and decreasing on [11/3, 5]. Hence, P is strictely increasing on [2, 11/3] and strictely decreasing on [11/3, 5], so the local maximum is reach at x= 11/3, and it's P(11/3) = 256/27.

Comment: Thank you, @WarriorOfLegend.  But notice that the question was asking for a clever solution.  Check Eric's comment --- he applies the rational root theorem and some polynomial and calculus knowledge to figure out that $x = 1$ is a local minimum and therefore the other root of the derivative must be the local maximum.